# Can Canada now be called an Olympic hockey dynasty?

Tags: olympics

I heard this is the first team to win back to back gold medals in hockey in the last 26 years. Does that deserve the title of "dynasty"?

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, Canada could have been considered a dynasty for the past 100 years now; there have been 12 best vs best tournaments in the history of hockey, this is how it breaks down:

1. 1976 Canada Cup
2. 1981 Canada Cup
3. 1984 Canada Cup
4. 1987 Canada Cup
5. 1991 Canada Cup
6. 1996 World Cup of Hockey
7. 1998 Olympics
8. 2002 Olympics
9. 2004 World Cup of Hockey
10. 2006 Olympics
11. 2010 Olympics
12. 2014 Olympics

Canada has won 8 of these tournaments, I'm sure you can pick out which ones, no other country has won more than 1. Canada has been a dynasty for the past…forever.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time a 'dynasty' refers to a team that has once consistently over a long period of time. Canadian hockey has indeed dominated the international ice for the past decade and become a superpower in the sport. It would be fair to say that their team is running the show when it comes to international ice time, but not necessarily a dynasty, as in competitions they have not always come out on top. It just happens that over the past six years they have built up an extremely strong team. If their streak continues into the next winter olympics, the world 'dynasty' would indeed be used to describe Canada's team.